# Force quit on Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm making a text game but can't get it to end the script half way through when the user pushes quit. I have tried quit, return and error -128 but none of them work.

The code isn't inside a tell/end tell because I'm not wanting to use an application, but I've tried putting it inside one with finder and that didn't work either..

Any help is appreciated :)

```
set temp to display dialog "Welcome" buttons {"Play", "Quit"}
if temp = "Quit" then
error number -128
end if

set temp to display dialog "What is your name?" default answer "Joe" buttons {"Submit"}
set userName to text returned of temp
etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution: define the **cancel** button.

```
display dialog "Welcome" buttons {"Play", "Quit"} cancel button "Quit"
-- no need to check the button returned, the script quit automatically when user cancelled
set temp to display dialog "What is your name?" default answer "Joe" buttons {"Submit"}
set userName to text returned of temp
etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get button returned:

```
if button returned of temp = "Quit" then
   error number -128
end if
```

Comment: Just tried it, it didn't work :(
Thanks anyway though

Comment: Ah brilliant, I even tried that one and wrote it wrong..  Thanks Nicael :)